# Recommendation for finding trends in variable data

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, clustering, trend

I have about 40 variables for each subject in a human population. For each time period, people join and exit the study. As a made up example, I want to see whether there are increases in average spending on movies as time progresses. The problem is that my population is very volatile, there could be 15% male in one time period and 99% male in another. Given that this is the case, how can I figure you whether the increase I observe is due to actual increase, population change or just variance?

What I'm looking for is what subject I should be learning to address this problem. A particular textbook on clustering, regression? Or something like that. I cannot change or resample the data I'm given and I'm looking for something that's masters or bachelors level.

Answer (score 1):

Look at **bootstrapping** first.

For example, you would do 100 random permutations of your data set, and check how many false findings you get with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

me thinks this is a pretty good case for a decision tree analysis. So i assume your 40 variables dont include the time period but that you have decent markers for your time period (P1 , P2 etc :) ) and you could use average money spent as a decision label. What the tree is going to do is tell you , for instance, during P1 if the subject was male and if he had a car and if he had a wife his average spending was > 200 bucks ..the tree will do this for all periods and then its a simple matter of visual interpretation for you to figure out the anwer to your problem..hope this helps